# ResourceConfig will be locked when adding extension module in Jersey

Tags: json, rest, jersey, jackson, moxy

I am trying to build a jax-rs web service using Jersey2.8. When I put a jar like **jersey-media-json-jackson-2.8.jar** or **jersey-media-moxy-2.8.jar** under WEB-INF/lib folder, the exception **"The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context"** will occur on the browser.
Why this issue happens and how could i fix this?

Comment: Solved. This is caused by lacking dependence jars. The error message puzzled me.

Comment: According to https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson, it said that you should register JacksonFeature.class in your own application implement, but i found that one MUST not do this. If you register the class, 404 error will occur and I don't know why.